# testing for all values in an array over a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of values that are produced from an equation.

e.g.

testArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

What I want to do is write a function to look for all the values **over** a particular value and output the result.

So for example, in the above testArray how would I return all the values over 7 (8,9, 10 only not including 7)?

Happy for the response to use Javascript and/or Jquery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
var testArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].filter(function(element) {
    return element > 7;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7KwM/).

Comment: Aha! I knew i was missing something obvious. This is perfect thankyou :D